# Request to refresh access token programmatically to facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cron

I am trying to build a website, which fetches all the posts from a facebook group, which can further be used to search through the posts. The main function of the website will be to search in the posts that are being fetched from facebook group.

I fetched the access token using my account, which I used to fetch the posts. To fetch new posts from the fb group, I plan to enqueue a cron job which fetches all the latest posts. To fetch these posts, I need a usable access token. The access token that I have now, will expire in few days.

Is there any way that I can refresh my access token automatically through a cron job instead of refreshing it manually every few days?